# Loop through 2 folders and perform raster calculation on the same file name

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, loop, iteration

I was able to run the below script from @EmilBrundage.

However, the raster to be calculated were not paired correctly.

I am trying to loop files from 2 folders and perform raster calculation afterwards. The sequence of calculation must be:

(1st) out-0225*out-0225 [from clip qx folder] + out-0225*out-0225 [from clip qy  folder]

(2nd) out-0226*out-0226 [from clip qx folder] + out-0226*out-0226 [from clip qy  folder]

(3rd) out-0227*out-0227 [from clip qx folder] + out-0227*out-0227 [from clip qy  folder]

and so on.

But then the script calculates like the image below.

[image: File pairing]

The script used is the ff:

```
import arcpy, os, math
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

ws1 = r"E:\clip_qx"
ws2 = r"E:\clip_qy"
outws = r"E:\ras_calc_qxy"

arcpy.env.workspace = ws1

rasterlist  = arcpy.ListRasters()

for r in rasterlist:
    r1 = arcpy.sa.Raster(r)
    r2 = arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(ws2,r1))
    result =  (r1*r1) + (r2*r2)
    result.save(os.path.join(outws, r))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not paired correctly"? Do they not line up or something? I am confused.

Comment: @jbchurchill, i edited the question. Kindly check it out. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In line

```
r2 = arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(ws2,r1))
```

you write `r1` at the end of the bracket.

I think this should be just `r`.